# eps images turned out to be shifted in pdf file

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, epstopdf, dvipdfmx

I am trying to include an image. This picture should be centered and should not exceed page width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{image.eps}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It looks perfectly in DVI file but fails in PDF during LaTex-DVI-PDF compilation. .eps file is converted to pdf with dvipdfm postprocessor but displays wrong. Here is the output screen.

[image]
!

So why is it shifted from the specified position and how it can be fixed?

`\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` and `\fbox{}` commands are unnecessarily here but help me to detect problem. I'm also unsuccessfully tried to use different graphicx package like `\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}` and `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`.

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.5105 and TeXnicCenter v2.02.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Perhaps the `.eps` itself causes this. Could you upload that file?

Comment: As Symbol 1 said, it could be a problem with the eps file. To reproduce the error we would need that. In the meantime, does the problem also occur via LaTeX->PS->PDF (with DviPS and ps2pdf as postprocessors)?

Comment: Yes @Manuel Weinkauf, the problem also occur via LaTex->PS->PDF. And I cant add .eps image via addimage icon due to its unavailable extension. here are links to this file ob Google Drive ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0vRzYikNc6aUHlwNG10TGJ5c28/view?usp=sharing)) and Yandex DIsk ([link](https://yadi.sk/d/gnrOenS8fBRL3))

Comment: It works if you use latex-dvips-ps2pdf but is misplaced if you use dvipdfm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

By default for latex `dvips` is assumed. texlive doesn't come with a `dvipdfm` option but does include `dvipdfmx.def` which seems to work well enough with `dvipdfm`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{image.eps}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is actually solves my problem with latex->dvi->pdf. From the other hand there is a strange result with latex->dvi. The picture is shifted now in the dvi-file the same way but to the right up corner. It seems that i have to implement if/else block to maintain usability in both cases.

Comment: @Yusa yes that's expected as xdvi is interpretting dvips specials and clearly in this case there is a difference in syntax. Is there a particular reason for using dvi rather than just converting the eps to pd then using pdflatex which is the far more common route these days?

Comment: @Yusa note the picture is not _in_ the dvi file. the tex `\special` just puts processor-specific instructions into the dvi to tell the dvi driver to include an eps. if you are using two different dvi programs (xdvi and dvipdfm) then you need to make the dvi in each case with the correct syntax \specials.

Comment: make sense, thx a lot